# 404 Error in Xampp

Tags: xampp

I have used Astro Theme and worked on xampp but I have a trouble that:
" Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404
localhost
Apache/2.4.43 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1f PHP/7.4.4 "

Have anybody can have me??

Comment: I'd guess this is a problem with your server's rewrite rules not being set up properly. You should find WordPress's suggested config on the 'permalinks' page in the admin site.

Comment: do you get this on every page on just some pages? was everything fine before you changed to this theme? maybe paste a screenshot or copy of the error?